# Element position in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array:

```
char[] modifiers = {'A', 'M', 'D'};
```

and a variable:

```
char a = 'D'
```

How to get position of variable value in array?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

This is the shortest way I know. I had this as a comment but now writing it as an answer. Cheers!

> Character[] array = {'A','B','D'};
>
> Arrays.asList(array).indexOf('D');

Comment: Well this doesn't work. Try it with the OP's values. It returns -1.

Comment: Great catch. fixed. The initialization will need to be with Character.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
int pos = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < modifiers.length; i++) {
  if(modifiers[i] == a) {
     pos = i;
     break;
  }
}
```

This will get the **first** occurrence of the value in variable `pos`, if there are multiple ones, or -1 if not found.

Answer (score 3):

Something along the lines may do the trick:

```
Collections.indexOfSubList(Arrays.asList(array), Arrays.asList('D'))
```

Trying to avoid a manual loop :p

Comment: Why not just use `Arrays.asList(array).indexOf('D');`?

Comment: @st0le you should make that an answer. It's the best solution to the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You could do it yourself easily enough, you can use the sort() and binarySearch() methods of the java.util.Arrays class, or you can convert the char [] to a String and use the String.indexOf() method.

Comment: +1. `new String(modifiers).indexOf('D')` is a pretty concise way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

**This is very simple and tested code for your reference**

```
String[] arrayValue = {"test","test1","test2"};
int position = Arrays.asList(arrayValue).indexOf("test");

position: 0th Position
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array and compare its elements to the variable, return the index, if equals. Return -1 if not found. You might want to consider using any implementation of `java.util.List`.