# Java - get element position in array

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm familiar with the ways I can get an element position in array, especially the ones showed here: [Element position in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234827/element-position-in-array)

But my problem is I can't figure out how to convert this code to fit my needs.

What I want to check is if a String has a match in an ArrayList and if so, what's the index of the String in the ArrayList.

The annoying part is I managed to verify the String is in the ArrayList (see first line of my code)

listPackages is the ArrayList

current_package is the String I want to find its position in listPackages.

Here's my code:

```
if (listPackages.contains(current_package)) {

        int position = -1;
        for(int j = 0; j < listPackages.size(); j++) {

            if(listPackages[j] == current_package) {
              position = j;
                  break;
              }
            }
    }
```

Would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: Also, please don't use == to compare objects in Java, even Strings. Always use equals method.

Comment: Thanks, you're right... honest mistake of copy-paste :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [`indexOf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
int index = listPackages.indexOf(current_package);
```

Note that you shouldn't generally use `==` to compare strings - that will compare *references*, i.e. whether the two values are references to the same object, rather than to equal strings. Instead, you should call `equals()`. That's probably what was going wrong with your existing code, but obviously using `indexOf` is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3):

just use the call `listPackages.indexOf(current_package);`

`ArrayList.contains(Object o)` calls `indexOf(Object o)` internally in ArrayList:

```
/**
 * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this list contains the specified element.
 * More formally, returns <tt>true</tt> if and only if this list contains
 * at least one element <tt>e</tt> such that
 * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;e==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(e))</tt>.
 *
 * @param o element whose presence in this list is to be tested
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if this list contains the specified element
 */
public boolean contains(Object o) {
return indexOf(o) >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you.change your code like this:

```
if (listPackages.contains(current_package)){
int position=listPackages.indexOf(current_package);
}
```

Also if you will make position variable as global you can access its value outside this block of code. :)

Comment: Works but no need to traverse the list twice. Just use indexOf. If the arraylist doesn't contain the string this will return -1

Comment: Yes you are right.But what if that ArrayList doesnot contain a String and you will try to find it's indexOf.Will there be any exception?I guess so but i have not tried this type though.

Answer (score 1):

use the indexof method to get the position -

```
listPackages.indexOf(current_package)
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)