# Search string array without a using a loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, search

I have the following array

```
String[] arrKey  = new String[] {"A","B","C","D","E",......"Y","Z"};
```

I would like to search the array and give me the index of where the letter is.
Say for example I want to search for the letter "E" and when I search the array it should give me the position of "E" so I should get index position 4. I don't want to do this in a loop. Is it possible? I have been looking all around and can't find an answer.

Comment: You could write a recursive method if you don't want to use an explicit loop.

Comment: No, it's impossible without loop.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution which is self contained and doesn't use loops or any other API call?

Answer (score 16):

> I don't want to do this in a loop.

There has to be a loop *somewhere* - either in your code or library code.

So yes, you can use

```
int index = Arrays.asList(arrKey).indexOf("E");
```

... but that will loop under the covers.

If you know that your array is sorted to start with, you can use:

```
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arrKey, "E");
```

That will be more efficient - but it's still a loop...

Of course, if you know that your array is *always* A-Z, then you *can* do it without a loop - but I assume your real case is more generalized...

Comment: What I meant about a loop is I didn't want to do a for loop. The above could be what I'm looking for. Will need to text.

Comment: Thanks Jon, 

When I try the above: 

  `int index = Arrays.asList(arrKey).indexOf("E");`

I get -1 as my answer regardless of which one letter I use.
When I try this one :
    
    `int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arrKey, "E");`

I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.String

I assume it has to do with the type of array?

Comment: @Dino: Then you must have a different array to the one you showed us. It sounds like you don't *really* have a String array.

Comment: I have actually used a `String c = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";` then `char[] arrKey = c.toCharArray();` and your code int `index = Arrays.binarySearch(arrKey, "E");` worked for me.                        I am not sure how it works but from what you said it loops? I am just curious as I am learning JAVA as when you look at the line there is no loop there just a line so I presume that JAVA (in the background) does it's own loop for that statement! Is that right?

Comment: @Dino: Right, so your code isn't as it is in your question (where you have a `String[]`). Your code should work if you use `'E'` instead of `"E"`. And yes, all of these loop. But if you've *really* got A...Z, you can just use `'E' - 'A'`... It would really help if you'd give us an accurate impression of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Jon please see my reply below.

Answer (score 2):

It is basically a interview question, to test your recursion skills, here is how you do it.

```
private static <T> int findIndex(T[] items, T item, int index) {
    if (items.length == index) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (items[index].equals(item)) {
        return index;
    }
    return findIndex(items, item, index+1);
}
```

Here is how you can run it

```
int val = findIndex(new String[]{"A","B","C"}, "C", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to deal with `char`s and not strings have a look at the [getNumericValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) method.

If you want a more general solution you should consider using a `Map<String,Integer>` rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

[Java - get element position in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581363/java-get-element-position-in-array)

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf

```
   return arrKey.get(arrKey.indexOf("E"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It only possible if you assume you have this array (or one similar) as you can calculate the index.

```
String s = "E";
int index = s.charAt(0) - 'E'; // == 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I am working on. This is what I have at the moment. It is just a practice round for me to practice JAVA and understand the Ceaser Cipher.

```
public class CeaserCipher
{
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter test letters for Caesar cipher in capitals");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();
    char[] strArray = input.toCharArray();

    System.out.print("What is the key: "); 
    int key = keyboard.nextInt();
    //String[] arrKey  = new String[] {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
    String c  = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char[] arrKey = c.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length ; i++){

        char cipherValue = strArray[i];
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arrKey, cipherValue);
        int j = (key + index)%26;
        System.out.print(arrKey[j]);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear why you've added this as an answer. Isn't this just basically acknowledging that my answer works, albeit using `char` instead of `String`?

Comment: OH I thought that you wanted to see my answer. I did try using String, but I kept getting an error message. That is why I converted to char.

Comment: Either should be fine - so long as you're consistent between "what's in your array" and "what you're looking for". So you can look for `'E'` in a `char[]`, or `"E"` in a `String[]`.

Comment: Ah Thanks a lot Jon, that is what I wanted to learn. That really clears it up for me. Reading your last comment made me happy to learn that either way is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recursion for this case:

```
let arr = ["A","B","C","D","E","Y","Z"];
let index = 0;

function find(str){
  if(str[0] === "E")
  { 
    return str[0];
  }
  else {
    str.shift();
```

> //removing 1st element from the str array and calling the function again

```
        index++;
        return find(str);
      }
    }
    
    console.log("Found",find(arr));
    console.log("at Index:",index);
    console.log("Peace Out! XD");
```