# How to get position of element in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I used following method to add my data to ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<Word>();
Word word = new Word();
word.set_id(id);
word.setWord(word);
word.setDefinition(definition);
wordList.add(word);
```

After the add some data, I want find the position of the any id which I want find in ArrayList.

Already I have tried following method to get position by id. But it isn't work.

```
int position = wordList.indexOf(id);
```

and

```
int position = wordList.lastIndexOf(id);
```

Both codes always generated "position = -1" as a result. How can I do that?

**Edited**

This is the code of the Word.java class. How can I implement equal method?

```
public class Word {
    private String _id, word, definition, favourite, usage;

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getDefinition() {
        return definition;
    }

    public void setDefinition(String definition) {
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    public String getFavourite() {
        return favourite;
    }

    public void setFavourite(String favourite) {
        this.favourite = favourite;
    }

    public String getUsage() {
        return usage;
    }

    public void setUsage(String usage) {
        this.usage = usage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Search for the object using indexOf if you can access the object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - get element position in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581363/java-get-element-position-in-array)

Comment: "how can I implement equals method" - it's not necessary, but your IDE should have the ability to generate it for you. Otherwise, there are lots of examples elsewhere how to do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`indexOf` is trying to compare Word objects. Your list doesn't contain ids as the elements, so you get -1.

You need to use a loop and search the list.

```
int id = 3; 
int position = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < wordlist.size(); i++) {
    if (wordlist.get(i).getId() == id) {
        position = i;
        // break;  // uncomment to get the first instance
    }
}
```

Note: this will search the whole list to find the last index of that id. So if there are duplicates and you only want the first one (or stop the loop as soon as you find what you want) add a `break` in the if statement.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help.. I used above code in AsyncTask class. It's work charm.

Comment: Although this answer is efficient right now, it's preferable to use java internal implementations in such cases and not write your own code. Things can change in future and those things are inculcated in java libraries. Also for a different amount of sub-sets or length, different algorithms are used to maximize performances in all cases. So I'd suggest creating a word object and passing that in the indexOf method to find the index. This will make it cleaner and scalable.

Comment: @AnkitBhatnagar  "Write your own code" does not coincide with "java internal implementation". Linear search algorithms are simple enough and will always remain efficient so "right now" does not apply. I don't see the need for a fully implemented equals method defined for an object when all you want to find is one value, not match every potential field of the object

Comment: @cricket_007 "equals" method if defined only for one field, it checks only one field, not all the fields. In future, if you've to scale further with some other field, you'll not have to change the code everywhere you've used manual iterations. It's encapsulating the logic at a place where it should be, not outside and everywhere where it's required.

Comment: But if you use `indexOf` when the `equals` method is "updated" with some other fields, then the manual iterations for only obtaining one field potentially become broken.

Comment: That is what I searching, but what is the better variant on kotlin maybe?

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement equals method in the "Word" object. Inside equals method you can apply equals only to id field.
2. Create a new Word object with that id and pass that object in indexOf. Don't pass the id in the indexOf. Pass the new of existing Word object with the required id.

Then indexOf will return the valid index of this word object.

Answer (score 0):

For searching the object in a list. you need to override equals method in your Word class. otherwise you will get -1. because indexOf internally used equals method to search the element in list.

Answer (score -1):

The class inside your list should implement hascode() and equals() in order to have indexOf() that works.

Comment: If using an integer for `indexOf`, that still won't work

Comment: Having a field named id does not let Java guess that it should be used as an Id. You also have to implement hashcode and equals based on that id field. In eclipse, you can simply select the id field and click on source, generate hashcode and equals using fields